# Why am I getting empty "Messages: " logging output when running Scrapy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, scrapy, web-crawler

My spider is running correctly and I managed to control the logging with e.g. this kind of code line:

> logging.info("MyCrawler built list of URLs!")

and output messages to console e.g.

> [root] INFO: MyCrawler built list of URLs!

When running the spider I get many of following kind of messages:

> 2017-08-25 13:40:15 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 26
>   pages (at 2 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min) Message:
>
> Message:
>
> Message:
>
> Message:
>
> Message:
>
> Message:
>
> Message:
>
> Message:
>
> 2017-08-25 13:41:12 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 42
>   pages (at 16 pages/min), scraped 8 items (at 8 items/min) Message:
>
> Message:
>
> Message:
>
> 2017-08-25 13:42:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 241
>   pages (at 199 pages/min), scraped 214 items (at 206 items/min)
>   2017-08-25 13:43:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 381
>   pages (at 140 pages/min), scraped 350 items (at 136 items/min)
>   2017-08-25 13:44:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 688
>   pages (at 307 pages/min), scraped 659 items (at 309 items/min)
>   2017-08-25 13:45:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 995
>   pages (at 307 pages/min), scraped 968 items (at 309 items/min)
>   2017-08-25 13:46:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1370
>   pages (at 375 pages/min), scraped 1340 items (at 372 items/min)
>   2017-08-25 13:47:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1676
>   pages (at 306 pages/min), scraped 1648 items (at 308 items/min)
>   2017-08-25 13:48:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1914
>   pages (at 238 pages/min), scraped 1886 items (at 238 items/min)
>   2017-08-25 13:49:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2189
>   pages (at 275 pages/min), scraped 2162 items (at 276 items/min)
>   2017-08-25 13:50:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2430
>   pages (at 241 pages/min), scraped 2402 items (at 240 items/min)
>   2017-08-25 13:51:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2678
>   pages (at 248 pages/min), scraped 2651 items (at 249 items/min)
>   2017-08-25 13:52:05 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 2952
>   pages (at 274 pages/min), scraped 2924 items (at 273 items/min)
>   Message:
>
> 2017-08-25 13:53:09 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 3166
>   pages (at 214 pages/min), scraped 3130 items (at 206 items/min)
>   Message:
>
> Message:

What does the empty line

> Message:

mean and how can I control it's visibility and content?

Comment: Post the complete scraper

Comment: They may just be debugging messages built into the library that you are using. Try changing logging level to INFO or ERROR and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @BobEzuba logging was already on INFO. Changed it to ERROR. Now "the Crawled 3166 pages..." messages are gone but the empty messages are still there.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I've many files, it's not just the spider (items.py etc). The most relevant piece of information which seems to be important for me is that I am using Selenium

Comment: Seems like you're having a `print` call somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Granitosaurus it's definitely not in the code I've written. I don't have any print in my Scrapy project. It must be coming either from Selenium or Scrapy

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, I discovered, that following piece of Selenium related code was responsible for generating empty messages:

```
while True:
    try:
        loadMoreButton = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loadMoreUpcomingPast"]')
        loadMoreButton.click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(self.delay) 
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

It's not the cleanest workaround, but here's what I did to get rid of the empty messages:

```
while True:
    try:
        loadMoreButton = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loadMoreUpcomingPast"]')
        loadMoreButton.click()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(self.delay) 
    except Exception as e:
        break
```

Am not sure if I need exception handling here at all. But, I didn't want to risk breaking any hours taking scraping process.